# How to Detect a Hidden Process in Linux

Tags: process, kernel, tasklist, rootkit

I have read somewhere that rootkits hide a process by dropping off its links in `task list`.First my question is when it is dropped off task list, how it can be scheduled in kernel 3.*? In fact I want to detect hidden processes by comparing `running` processes in `task list` and processes in something like `runqueue`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use unhide

```
apt-get install unhide
```

it compare running processes by various methods for example :

```
 getpriority() 
 getpgid() 
 getsid() 
 sched_getaffinity() 
 sched_getparam() 
 sched_getscheduler() 
 sched_rr_get_interval()
```

...